# How to run batch file for PostgreSQL from any place?

Tags: windows, postgresql, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run batch file for PostgreSQL database and server I'm using this one:

```
@ECHO ON
@SET PATH="%~dp0";%PATH%
@SET PGDATA=%~dp0\data
@SET PGUSER=postgres
@SET PGPORT=5432
@SET PGLOCALEDIR=%~dp0\share\locale
"%~dp0initdb" -U postgres -D %~dp0/data -E UTF8
"%~dp0pg_ctl" -w -D "%~dp0/data" -l logfile start
psql.exe -U postgres -f C:\pgsql\bin\db_create.sql postgres
"%~dp0pg_ctl" -D "%~dp0/data" stop
```

this works just fine if the directory of the batch file and the postgres folder were in:

> C:\pgsql\bin

but if the directory of the batch file and the postgres folder are somewhere else, like:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\My App\My App\bin

the batch won't work and gives me an error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't quote your paths:

```
"%~dp0initdb" -U postgres -D "%~dp0/data" -E UTF8
                             ^----------^---missing
```

If you'd actually read the error message, "Too many arguments, first is 'files" you'd have seen this.

Comment: ooh i didn't notice because it woks just fine in  "C:\pgsql\bin"  and now it gives me other error : 
creating directory C:/Program Files (x86)/My App/My App/bin/data ... initdb: could not create directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/My App/My App/bin/data": Permission denied

how i can resolve that please

Comment: @HamzaGeeK Do ***not*** put the data directory into `Program Files`. That directory is protected for a reason.